# Laravel eloquent: use Model from fixed array

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Is there any way that I can dynamicly set Model source and that this source will be used by all other models and relationships etc.

For example:

```
   \App/TestModel::setSourceFromArray($array);

   $other = App/OtherModel::find(5);  

   var_dump($other->test);  //  belongs to TestModel
```

and it will return query from database to find "other" model with id 5, and then join with prefilled array if specified on already configured foreign key in model and if it is not fallback to database connection.

Is there something out of the box for this behaviour or i will need to write my own extension?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is not, because `Builder` methods are linked with a single data source, that data source can have multiple implementations for different DB types

Comment: It kinda sounds like you're looking for something akin to [contextual binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/container#contextual-binding).